# File not uploaded more then 300Mb in php

Tags: php

I try to upload 300Mb file but not uploaded and not show any error message. Variable size display if i check as phpinfo() is

```
post_max_size 750M
upload_max_filesize 750M
memory_limit 800M
max_execution_time  9001
```

if i try small file its working fine. like 3mb.
Please help me to find solution.

Comment: have you checked the net connection?

Comment: Don't forget to check your webserver configuration.

Comment: What you mean by webserver configuration, As i checked info by phpinfo() function and shows you the variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proble is solved. I need to set these variable on modsec2.user.conf file

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 1073741824
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 1073741824
```

This is a apache server file. and error was shown on Apache error log.

Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

What I've always found is that `post_max_size` needs to be bigger than `upload_max_filesize`, and I usually aim for having `post_max_size` being three times the other setting, in this case `post_max_size 2250M` though that's not ideal.

I'd also suggest setting the `memory_limit` higher too, though max execution time should generally be fine.

Really though, using a chunking solution such as [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) or [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) is probably better in the long term.

Comment: I changed the post_max_size, also try some other changes but not getting success.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making these changes?

Comment: how to restart Apache on server, from cpanel or from AMP account?

Comment: Is it your own server, that you installed cPanel on? Or do you have a hosting account with a hosting company? If the latter, maybe ask them to do it.

Comment: this is  a hosting account

Comment: In which case you probably need to talk to your host. Or implement something like Plupload or jQuery File Upload instead to upload the file in small pieces.

Comment: I also try Plupload. but after 100% it show 200 not found error

Comment: Now my variable size is 
post_max_size 800M
upload_max_filesize 750M
memory_limit 2048M
max_execution_time  17100
max_input_time 17100

Comment: But now if i try to print $_file[finename][tmp_name] it show nothing and page redirect to home. but for less then 128M file it show /tmp/phpSsldj like that.